# Rails_admin, change values of one field by value of another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I have three models: `Category`, `SubCategory` and `Item`.

`SubCategory` belongs to `Category`

`Item` belongs to `Category` and `SubCategory`

In rails_admin's `create` and `edit` page, where I can assign values for items, values of categories and subcategories are shown as **enums of ALL existing Categories and SubCategories**.

When I create new `Item`, I will select the `Category`. I want to keep only values of `SubCategories`, which is belongs to selected category, and only be able to select them.

How it is possible to make rails_admin to select SubCategories values depending on what Category is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `bindings` hash to get access the current record instance

> The field declarations also have access to a bindings hash which contains the current record instance in key :object and the view instance in key :view. Via :object we can access other columns' values and via :view we can access our application's view helpers

From: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields

so in your case for example, in your `Item` rails_admin configuration

```
bindings[:object].category
```

will give you the current selected category for the item